# JavaScript element.classList.remove not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove a class from a certain element whenever the user clicks a button.

In the process I check whether the element has the class before removing it.

I am using a React component and I'm setting the class variable this.images in `componentDidMount` Also, the console.log in there confirms the array of images that i need.

```
    componentDidMount() {
        this.images = document.querySelectorAll(".project-image");
        console.log(this.images);
    }

    renderNextImage() {
        for (let i = 0, ilen = this.images.length; i < ilen; i++) {
            if (!this.images[i].classList.contains('d-none')) {
                this.images[i].classList.add('d-none');
                this.toggleNextImage(i);
            }
        }
    }
    toggleNextImage(count) {
        let max = this.images.length - 1;
        if (count < max) {
            count++;
            if (this.images[count].classList.contains('d-none')) {
                console.log("element contains class d-none");      // THIS WORKS
                this.images[count].classList.remove('d-none');
            }
        }
    }
```

The console log shows up in my console but the actual classList.remove part doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve], including the markup for the elements, how you are constructing the class and how you are calling the method?

Comment: I don't know if it helps but I just checked and the classList attribute have a toggle  method

Comment: Btw, you don't need the `if (….contains(…))` check, just call `remove` - it won't error when the class doesn't exist.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: @WolganEns He's not actually toggling. One function always adds, the other one always removes.

Comment: The logic in the two loops does not make that much sense to me. Seems way to complicated for what you are doing.

Comment: @epascarello how should i do it then?

Comment: @Barmar Just asking :)

Comment: @epascarello Where do you see two loops? There's no loop in `toggleNextImage()`.

Comment: @Barmar You have the renderNextImage image in a loop and it calls toggleNextImage with a loop and it is doing a lot more looping than what is needed.

Comment: @epascarello `renderNexdtImage` isn't in a loop. He hasn't shown the code that calls it, but says it happens when he click a button.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're doing this in a loop. In `renderNextImage()` you call `toggleNextImage()`, which removes the class from the next element in the list. Then the loop repeats with the next value of `i`, which adds the class back.

You need to break out of the loop when you find the image to toggle.

```
renderNextImage() {
    for (let i = 0, ilen = this.images.length; i < ilen; i++) {
        if (!this.images[i].classList.contains('d-none')) {
            this.images[i].classList.add('d-none');
            this.toggleNextImage(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, adding break; fixed it. Somebody in the comments said that this is not the best way of doing this. How would one do this more efficient?

Comment: You can save the index of the current image in a global variable, and just increment it. Or you can use `querySelector(".d-none")` and get the index of that element in its parent element.

Answer (score 0):

This vanilla js remove works just if you apply it on the element, like in this example. You need to make sure if this code (this.images[count]) represents an element.

```js
// JavaScript
var div = document.querySelector('div');
div.classList.remove('myClass');
```

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). See [why do I need 50 reputation to comment, what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) for an explanation.

Comment: I agree with @Barmar don't ask a question in an answer

Comment: If it didn't represent the element, how could the `contains()` test work?

Comment: Yeah, I know man. But as you said. I can't create comments yet. So if I am trying to help with a comment I just post like I did.

Comment: The reason why i've added the contains() part, is because i wanted to make sure it did actually represent an element.

Comment: @LeoRossetti if you can't comment yet, then earn the 50 rep by giving answers you're confident about

Comment: The restrictions are there for  a reason. You shouldn't try to get around the restriction by posting an answer instead of a comment. I know you're trying to be helpful, but you're also breaking the site rules.

Comment: Did you read the posts I linked to? It specifically say "Can I put my comment in an answer? No"

Comment: I know, you are right guys. Thank you for explain! ;)